# Tag tips/warnings

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, warnings

Inspired by: [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632)

---

It seems this hasn't been proposed on this site yet, so here goes...

We could consider adding tag-specific messages that pop-up when you try to post a question with a particular tag. For example, when using a more general tag like [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus), it could prompt you to consider adding more specific tags with a list of similar tags. For tags that get high percentages of questions that end up closed, we could link them to the [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Not every tag needs one, but it might be a nice feature to have anyways.

Comment: This [suggestion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28060/what-about-suggested-tags-feature) by Martin seems related. There's another one about tag warning [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21873/do-we-want-tag-warnings-and-for-which-tags), a similar one I asked sometimes ago [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21669/a-warning-to-those-who-use-only-rare-new-tags)

Comment: Just to clarify, is this actually different from this previous suggestions: [Do we want tag warnings, and for which tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21873) (I might be wrong, but I think that none of the suggestions listed there has been implemented.)

Comment: @JohnMa thank you very much, those links are certainly the thing I intended here.

Comment: @Martin No, that is exactly what I want. I have to wonder why it never took off. Not enough support?

Comment: Since you said yourself that it's the same, I voted to close as a duplicate. (I waited for two weeks - which is a period during which post can get into community bulletin if it has score at least three.) If you want to revive the old topic, one thing worth trying is to check whether there are some other suggestions that can be added there. (One tag which is often used incorrectly was mentioned [in the Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2018/5/17) just a few days ago.)